# paddingOuter gets me a huge outer padding

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar graph at http://hahnsb0579.liveblog365.com/ and currently having an issue with the `paddingOuter`.

I get a huge padding at the top if I set `.paddingOuter(0.11)`.
but if I change it to `.paddingOuter(0.10)`, seems like it's just working fine.
I've been trying to solve this issue for 2 days already but couldn't solve it.

The key piece of code related to this issue is as below.

```
const yScale0 = d3.scaleBand()
                .domain(nexMeritDataObjBefore.members.map(function (e) {
                    return e.name;
                }))
                .rangeRound([0, yRangeMax])
                .paddingOuter(0.11)
                .paddingInner(0.2)
                .align(0.8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`band.round`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#band_round) (which is used by `rangeRound`) says:

> Note that if the width of the domain is not a multiple of the cardinality of the range, there may be leftover unused space, even without padding!

Therefore, a simple solution is just using `range` instead:

```
.range([0, yRangeMax])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! You're a genius! I never knew about that fact, so I could never find where the bug came from.